# How to add header to a file using sed command in python

Tags: python, linux, sed

I'm trying to add the following line to the beginning of file using sed command in python:

```
ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3

Command: sed -i '1i ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3' file.csv
```

The above command is working fine from bash. But when i am trying to run the same command from python I am getting error.

```
cmd =["sed", "-i", "'1i ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3'", "file.csv"]
```

i got this error message

```
"sed: -e expression #1, char 1:unkown command: `''\n"
```

Please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`s) are interpreted by shell to treat the enclosed sequence of characters as one argument to the command. When you run a command along with its arguments as a list with `subprocess.run` in Python, each list item would be passed to the command as-is as an argument, so you should not use single quotes to enclose any of the arguments:

```
cmd = ["sed", "-i", "1i ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3", "file.csv"]
```

Otherwise the single quotes themselves would be part of the arguments, which in your case get interpreted by `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `shlex` lib to split your bash command in python.

For example:

```
$ cat test.txt
abc

$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess, shlex
>>> subprocess.run(shlex.split("sed -i '1i ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3' test.txt"))
CompletedProcess(args=['sed', '-i', '1i ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3', 'test.txt'], returncode=0)
>>> 

$ cat test.txt 
ID|SEC_NO|SEC_CD|SEC_DATE|SEC_ID1|SEC_DESC1|SEC_ID2|SEC_DESC2|SEC_ID3|SEC_DESC3
abc
```